# script loaded asynchronously using appendChild gets loaded last

Tags: javascript

I created a script that add javascript files by appending it to the `head` tag.

Using the code below that I created:

```
var Dim = (function(s){ 
    var storage; 
    function loadError (oError) {
        throw new URIError("The script " + oError.target.src + " is not accessible.");
    }
    return {
        require : function(script,callback){
            var oScript = document.createElement("script");
            oScript.type = "text\/javascript";
            oScript.onerror = loadError;
            if (callback) { 
                oScript.onload = callback; 
            }
            document.head.appendChild(oScript);
            oScript.src = script;
        }
    };
})();
```

When we use the script like this:

```
Dim.require("script.js", function(){alert(token)}); alert(token);
```

and script.js code is:

```
alert(" Ok"); var token = " Hello";
```

The `alert(token)` throws an error.

Can anyone point me the Problem?

[Question was edited]

Comment: [Works for me](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qjn17RQ0ye4OmXcZeTDo?p=preview).

Comment: I also do not see why it would fail.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder It says to my console "token is not defined".

Comment: @MMJM: The link above, which is just your code wrapped in a plnkr, 1. doesn't show that error, and 2. does show an alert with the contents of `token` (`"Hello"`).

Comment: add relative path for script.js

Comment: @AlpeshJikadra: *"The problem is the script is loaded, but I cannot use its content."*

Comment: MMJM - You've said *"...the script is loaded, but..."*: How do you know the script is loaded? Do you see the `Ok` alert?

Comment: Which browser you use ?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder : But when I try to alert token outside of the "Dim.require()", it shows this error.

Comment: @MMJM — Define "outside". The script.js file that alerts it is *outside*, but as TJ's demo shows, it alerts fine. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: You are getting the error because, you are loading the script asynchronously.

Comment: I edited it again, but with two alerts. But I only receives one alert instead of two.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim.require("script.js", function(){alert(token)}); alert(token);
```

It runs first alert because its in callback which is called when the script is loaded by the browser.

```
if (callback) { 
  oScript.onload = callback; 
}
```

And second is not giving you an alert because it gives you an error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: token is not defined

You are loading your `script.js` asynchronously and while executing second alert , the `script.js` not loaded yet.

Comment: Thanks. I dont know much about asynchronous scripts

Comment: @MMJM check the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement)